# Cannot find symbol: Float.BYTES, Integer.BYTES

Tags: java, opengl, integer, jogl

When running a jogl script given to me by my lecturer, I got the following errors, both are "cannot find symbol"

```
symbol: variable BYTES
location: class Float
```

and

```
variable: BYTES
location: class Integer
```

Which is unusual as the code worked fine when my housemate ran it. Note that I have the latest version of java sdk (9).

Any ideas of how I can fix this error? The first occurrence of the error is in the line

```
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Float.BYTES * vertices.length, fb, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

where the object gl is an instance of GL3 in the jogl library.

Comment: Classes `java.lang.Float` and `java.lang.Integer` do indeed each have a static `BYTES` field, but only since Java 8.  If the very same code works for someone else but not for you, then the most likely explanation is that you are using an earlier version of Java than Java 8.  Note well that you can have multiple Java SDKs and Java VMs installed at the same time, so simply having the Java 9 SDK installed does not guarantee that that's what you're running the code on.

Comment: Rather use com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT and SIZEOF_INT from GlueGen which is necessary to run JOGL if and only if you want to run your program with Java <= 1.7. Otherwise, follow John's advise above. By the way, JOGL specific questions should be asked on our official forum.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is right, check java compilation version.